# margin-top issue. All my images move when I add more code, and when I try to move them back they all move at the same time

Tags: html, css

So, upon attempting to move one of the images on the site by changing the "margin-top", instead of just that image moving all of them do.

Can mess around with the site here.
http://spoon.fluxdev.nl/

Also if you believe I should do anything else to improve it, please say. The background is setup that way for a reason though.

This is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="/images/hymn-logo.png" style="width:476px;height:174px;">
</div>

<div id="content">
    <img id="username" style="width:247px;height:43px;">
    <img id="password" style="width:247px;height:43px;">
    <input type="image" id="request-password" src="/images/request-password.png" style="width:248px;height:36px;">

    <form id="form" action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="image" id="login" name="login" src="/images/login.png" style="width:248px;height:36px;">
    <input type="text" id="username-text" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width:150px;height:45px;">
    <input type="password" id="password-text" name="password" placeholder="********" style="width:150px;height:45px;">
    </form>

</div>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code.

```
body {
    background-image: url("/images/background.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #1B1D1F;
}

#logo {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    outline: none;
}

#login {
    margin-top: -73px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    padding: 1px;
}

#request-password {
    margin-top: 49px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    padding: 1px;
}

#username {
    background-image: url("/images/text-input.png");
    margin-top: 194px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    content: '';
}

#password {
    background-image: url("/images/text-input.png");
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    content: '';
}

#username-text {
    margin-top: -147px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
}

#password-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    outline: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing has worked. Thanks.

Comment: Where are your `body` tags?

Comment: Just added it in, didn't solve it. Changed nothing. If you go to my site and right click and press "Inspect Element" on Google Chrome and then try to change the margin-top: px to another number, you'll see what I mean. :(

Comment: @WesFoster Like `html` and `head` tags, `body` tags are optional.

Comment: @Spewni You put in the start tag for body in the wrong position. Anyway, which of the images were you trying to move? It's probably the collapsing margins problem. Give its parent a padding instead of a margin.

Comment: Well, I still have the problem. Was looking at collapsing margins previously and tried to fix it, but it didn't work. :l Seems no one knows. I need to move ALL of the images on the site apart from logo / background. I mean, they're in a decent position currently but they randomly mess up and then it takes me ages to get them to how they are now because they all decide to randomly move at the same time. (so all 5 move upwards when I try to move one up)